# Power BI - How to calculate percent difference between two different values of one column within a matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Power BI newbie here, which is probably obvious.  In the example of a matrix below, Term 1 and Term 2 are values from a variable called "Term" that I've placed in the Columns box. I'd like to add the "% Change" column as seen below, but I'm having trouble doing this. It seems like there would be an easy way to do this either with DAX or built-in options, but I'm unaware due to lack of experience. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

ROW:
Campus

COLUMN:
Term

VALUES:
Count

| Campus | Term 1 | Term 2 | Percent Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Camp A | 100 | 900 | __% |
| Camp B | 1400 | 2600 | __% |

Answer (score 0):

The measure you are looking for is

```
Percent Diff = 
DIVIDE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Term 2] ),
    SUM ( 'Table'[Term 1] )
) - 1
```

The point is that measures only work with aggregations, SUM in this case.

Comment: Thanks.  I did this, however Term 2 and Term 1 are not different columns - they are different categories within the same variable "Term," so the bracket notation isn't working.  I did try using your script with 'Table'[Term] = "Term 1", however this didn't seem to work since SUM appears to only accept column references and not values.

Comment: If your underlying data doesn't look like the presented table above you need to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
= SUM([Term 1])/((SUM([term 1])+SUM([Term 2]))/2)
```